# Jquery disable slide function on

Tags: jquery

I am using smart slider (http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-slidertrackbar-smart-slider/ )

Which is a nice jquery.

For one use on one page though; I want the slider to appear though I want to disable the sliding effect. So it's just visual and not an interactive element. There is not a lot of documentation to this one and my changes seem to blow it up. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

// JS

```
$('#trackbar1').strackbar({ 
    callback: onTick1, 
    defaultValue: 20, 
    sliderHeight: 25, 
    sliderWidth: 500, 
    style: 'style1', 
    animate: true, 
    ticks: false, 
    labels: false, 
    trackerHeight: 20, 
    trackerWidth: 20 
});
});

function onTick1(value) {
    $('#percentageworked').val(+ value);
}
```

// HTML

```
<div style="position: relative" class="CF"><div id="trackbar1"></div></div>
```

Comment: Why not just use an image?

Comment: Hi @EternalHour, I don't want to use an image as it is pulling dynamic data from a database. If you you do not have the privileges to change the slider, I still want them to view the progress. If I made it images, I would need to make 100 images - That's not my ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable it.

```
$('#trackbar1').strackbar({ 
               callback: onTick1, 
               defaultValue: 20, 
               sliderHeight: 25, 
               sliderWidth: 500, 
               style: 'style1', 
               animate: true, 
               ticks: false, 
               labels: false, 
               trackerHeight: 20, 
               trackerWidth: 20 
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: cheers again for your thoughts, though unfortunately your solution doesn't have the desired result.

Comment: It just kills it / doesn't make the slider appear.